# While loops in python while condition being at the end

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, break

I’m trying to write a program that has while true: at the start and then at the end asks the user if they want to repeat.

```
While True:
 print(“I will list the prime numbers between 0 and N”)
 N=input(“up to what number will I list the prime numbers?”)

 print (“prime numbers between 0 and”,N,” are:”)
 for no in range (2,N)
   if no>1:
       prime=True 
   for i in range (2, no):
      if (no % i) == 0:
          prime=False
          break
   if prime: 
       print(no)
 print(“would you like to enter a new range?”)
 response= input(“Enter yes or press enter key to exit”)

if response == yes:
         True
```

But no matter what is entered it keeps repeating

I tried adding an
else:
break

But it would say break away out of the loop of
I’m not sure what to do

Comment: Your code is syntactically broken in lots of ways. In any case, `break` only applies to the inner `for` loop and not the outer `while` loop

Comment: Note that Python keywords are case sensitive. The code, as shown, is not runnable

Comment: `else: break` is exactly the right thing to do -- I'm not sure what you mean by "but it would say break away out of the loop".  You need to break the loop if you want to stop repeating; that's what breaking the loop *means*.

Comment: Don't write code in a word processor -- it's doing a lot of silly stuff like capitalizing keywords and converting `""` to `“”`, both of which stop the code from working.  Use an IDE (VSCode is a pretty nice free one), or a plain text editor (vi, Notepad, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version, with fixes commented:

```
while True:  # needs to be 'while', not 'While'!
    print("I will list the prime numbers between 0 and N")  # use regular "", not “”
    N = int(input("up to what number will I list the prime numbers?"))  # make it an int!

    print("prime numbers between 0 and", N, "are:")
    for no in range(2, N):  # need a : to start the for loop
        # no starts at 2, so it will always be >1.  No "if" needed.
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, no):
            if no % i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime: 
            print(no)
    print("would you like to enter a new range?")
    response = input("Enter yes or press enter key to exit")
    if response != "yes":  # need quotes around "yes" to make it a string
        break
    # loop automatically continues if not broken
```

The part that's directly pertinent to your original question is at the very end -- what you want to do is `break` the loop if it's time to stop the program (i.e. if they didn't enter `"yes"`).  If not broken, the loop will continue automatically since it's in a `while True:`.

This part:

```
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, no):
            if no % i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime: 
            print(no)
```

can also be written more simply as:

```
        for i in range(2, no):
            if no % i == 0:
                break
        else: 
            print(no)
```

The `else:` block after a `for:` is executed at the end of the loop, but only if it's not stopped early with a `break`; you can therefore use it for cases like this where you want to test a bunch of conditions, stop the loop if one of them is true, and do something else otherwise.

This is such a common use case that there's an even simpler way to do it, using the built-in `all` function:

```
        if all(no % i for i in range(2, no)):
            print(no)
```

Here the `all` function tests that all elements of the iterable are true (note that `no % i` is considered "truthy" as long as it doesn't equal zero), and returns `True` or `False` accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using True as the while condition, use a variable as the condition such as:

```
while run
```

If you use True as the while condition True will always be true, so you have to use a variable in order for it to change.

Updated Code

```
run = True
While run:
 print(“I will list the prime numbers between 0 and N”)
 N=input(“up to what number will I list the prime numbers?”)

 print (“prime numbers between 0 and”,N,” are:”)
 for no in range (2,N)
   if no>1:
       prime=True 
   for i in range (2, no):
      if (no % i) == 0:
          prime=False
          break
   if prime: 
       print(no)
 print(“would you like to enter a new range?”)
 response= input(“Enter yes or press enter key to exit”)

if response == yes:
         run = True
else
         run = False
```

Comment: `While run:` is still invalid. You've only cleared up 90% of their errors

Comment: I take it back - `print(no)` too. I'm done going through the code

Comment: Poor advice. *while True* is a common and perfectly valid paradigm used in conjunction with *break*

Comment: This is full of syntax errors... Please *test your code* before posting it!